# Can I just drop osgi.enterprise.jar in my equinox plugins folder?

Tags: java, jdbc, osgi, enterprise, equinox

I'm interested in the OSGi Enterprise specification. At the moment I'm only interested in the JDBC connectivity, but that may change.

At http://www.osgi.org/Download/Release4V42 I can find the osgi.enterprise.jar (the companion code link). Can I just install it in my equinox container and use it?

I had the impression that some of the classes are overlapping (for instance org.osgi.service.component), doesn't this lead to problems? Or should I then just uninstall the org.eclipse.osgi.services bundle and use the osgi.enterprise instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't do that.
The file from OSGI.org is mostly interfaces, it is not complete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by "J-16 SDiZ" is correct, in that the `osgi.enterprise.jar` is pure interfaces rather than implementations.

You also asked about the overlap with the `org.eclipse.osgi.services` bundle… in fact the OSGi enterprise JAR should be a strict superset of it. There is not much problem with having both these bundles installed but it is also not really necessary, so to minimise confusion I would probably remove `org.eclipse.osgi.services`.